# SQL Teradata - Adding Column of first row data and so on w/ restrictions

Tags: sql, teradata

**Goal:** Take the current row of the table and find the most recent item of that customer and append that item data in the next column. If the most recent item is the item 1 of that row then it should proceed to the next row. The logic should always go the the very first row of that customer. Order is based on Transaction Date and partitioned by customer ID. Example of base data provided below in addition to what the desired result set should look like after running the script.

**Restrictions:** I need this script to work in a CRM tool. Specifically Aprimo/CIM by teradata. With that being said I cannot use CTEs (With) or volatile tables. I also do not want to create multiple joins into itself because of the table volume.

**What I have done Thus Far:** I feel that the best approach may be to utilize the Window Function, but finding myself creating a lot of nested case statements. I really wanted to know if there was a better way to get the answer i am looking for. I might have to just suck it up and do a join into itself.

[Base table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbq9v.png)

[Desired Result Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkIiA.png)

**Quick Start Base Table:**

```
CREATE  VOLATILE TABLE Base
(
customer_id  int
, trans_date date
, item varchar(1)
 ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;


Insert Into Base (123,'2017-01-01','A');
Insert Into Base (123,'2017-01-02','B');
Insert Into Base (123,'2017-01-03','C');
Insert Into Base (123,'2017-01-04','D');
Insert Into Base (123,'2017-01-05','E');
Insert Into Base (999,'2017-01-06','F');
Insert Into Base (999,'2017-01-07','G');
Insert Into Base (999,'2017-01-08','H');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some CASEs, but not *lots* :-)

```
SELECT 
   dt.*,
   CASE
      WHEN rn = 1 
      THEN Min(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN item end) Over (PARTITION BY customer_id)
      ELSE Min(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN item end) Over (PARTITION BY customer_id)
   END,
   CASE
      WHEN rn <=2
      THEN Min(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN item end) Over (PARTITION BY customer_id)
      ELSE Min(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN item end) Over (PARTITION BY customer_id)
   END,
   CASE
      WHEN rn <= 3
      THEN Min(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN item end) Over (PARTITION BY customer_id)
      ELSE Min(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN item end) Over (PARTITION BY customer_id)
   END
FROM
 (
   SELECT 
      Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY trans_date) AS rn
      ,base.*
   FROM Base
 ) AS dt
 ORDER BY customer_id, trans_date
```